# calculate size of sample to reach wanted probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

> You are recording neural activity in a cortical brain region. This
> brain region is known to contain excitatory and inhibitory neurons
> randomly distributed in space. In the cortex, the number of excitatory
> neurons is 4 times than the inhibitory neurons. You record blindly the
> neural activity, that is, you don’t know the type of the recorded
> neurons.  Note that each time you stick your electrode you might
> record the same neuron
>
> 1. Your recorded 100 neurons. How many neurons you expect to see from each type?
> 2. How many neurons must you record so that you will have at least one neuron from each type with probability of >0.95? (use matlab to
>    estimate the number, it is not easy to solve the equation
>    analytically)

1. I think that the answer for this is 80/20, am I right? (seems to easy to be true)
2. I'm not sure how to start with this. am I suppose to calculate the CDF? I was thinking that if the   probability of hitting inhibitory neuron is the smallest(0.2?) than I should just calculate the value of X for CDF(X) =0.95. is this the correct way to solve this?

Comment: @NickPeterson thanks. I see the logic in your solution, but do you think that my suggestion is wrong? because I get same result by plugin CDF(14) in matlab. they asked to "use matlab to estimate the number" and to not solve it analytically,  so I figured that they wanted me to try all values from CDF(1) to CDF(14) and see which value reaches ~0.95

Comment: @KaranElangovan please see comment above.

Comment: ... the CDF of what variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): spot on.

A hint for (2): note that
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{at least one of each})&=1-P(\text{all excitatory or all inhibitory})\\
&=1-(P(\text{all excitatory})+P(\text{all inhibitory})\\
&=1-P(\text{all excitatory})-P(\text{all inhibitory}).
\end{align*}
$$
If you take $n$ measurements, can you compute the probability that they were all excitatory?  The probability they were all inhibitory?

Comment: thanks, please see question in the main comments

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right for the first part.

For the second part, say we record n neurons.

What's the probability that we don't have at least one of each type?

That's P(no Es) + P(no Is) (we can't have none of either so these cases are disjoint)

P(no Es) = P(all Is)
P(no Is) = P(all Es)

So our probability is $ (\frac15)^n + (\frac45)^n $

So the probability there is at least one of each type, P(n):
$$ P(n) = 1 - (\frac15)^n - (\frac45)^n $$

We want the smallest integer n so $P(n) > 0.95 $
I'm not sure how we could solve this with algebra so I just used a table of values, to find that the smallest is $n = 14$

Comment: thanks, please see question in the main comments